# zoo-project installation

Tags: installation, ubuntu, wps, zoo-project

While following the documentation given [here](http://zoo-project.org/docs/install/debian.html) for Ubuntu 14.04

on the command  " ./configure --with-js --with-python "

When i check the installation logs there are some "no"

my concern is shall i proceed with next step or these "no" are optional ?

Please refer the installation logs given below

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please copy & paste information in as text not images. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-cut-copy-and-paste-in-the-terminal-in-ubuntu